# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action "project/users/loginCompleted", reducer "company" returned undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola, tengo un problema en el reducer.js, el cual me provoca que me salga el error del título.

Estoy haciendo una app en la que tengo que crear una compañía cuando el usuario se registra.
El problema viene cuando cierro el navegador y vuelvo a abrirlo e inicio sesión después de haber creado la compañía. En este caso company es nulo en next state aunque la haya creado.

Esto creo que se soluciona desde el reducer.js, como tengo en el código que voy a adjuntar, pero me saca un error y no consigo encontrar como arreglarlo.

reducer.js:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import users from '../users';
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    companyCategories: null,
    company: null,
};

const company = (state = initialState.company, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        //El error viene con estas línea de código
        /*->*/ case users.actionTypes.LOGIN_COMPLETED:
        /*->*/     return action.authenticatedUser.company;

        case actionTypes.ADDED_COMPANY_COMPLETED:
            return action.company;
        
        case actionTypes.MODIFY_COMPANY_COMPLETED:
            return action.company;

        default:
            return state;

    }

}

const companyCategories = (state = initialState.companyCategories, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.FIND_ALL_COMPANY_CATEGORIES_COMPLETED:
            return action.companyCategories;

        default:
            return state;

    }

}

const reducer = combineReducers({
    companyCategories,
    company
});

export default reducer;
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.